# Filter Date by FinancialYear

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a table where i needed to filter the data by financial year.

Financial year is between `April 1 of current year` and `March 31st of next year`.For example:The current year is `2016` so the current financial year comes between `April 1 2016` and `March 31 2017`.

The table

```
Id    CenterId    SlNo        Date
 1        1         5        2016-01-09 10:51:43.480 
 2        2         10       2016-01-09 10:51:43.480
```

I wanted to get the `Slno` where the `CenterId=1` and `Date will between current financial year`.

My concern is `Do i need another column of date for filtering financial year`.

Any help is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can do it without creating a new column. Simply calculate the current financial year dates like this:-

```
DateTime currentFinancialYearStartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 4, 1);
DateTime currentFinancialYearEndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, 3, 31);
```

Then, Simply use them in your filter like this:-

```
var result = dbContext.Sample.Where(x => x.CenterId == 1 
                                      && x.Date >= currentFinancialYearStartDate 
                                      && x.Date <= currentFinancialYearEndDate)
                             .Select(x => x.Slno);
```